# How to save a GIF on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, image-manipulation, uiimage

how can I save a GIF on the iPhone? The SDK includes only UIImageJPEGRepresentation and UIImagePNGRepresentation but nothing for GIFs or other image formats, is there a way to convert a UIImage to a GIF and save it?

GM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a library I wrote for encoding GIF images on the iPhone, if anyone reading this is interested:

http://jitsik.com/wordpress/?p=208

Comment: nice library! is there an example snippet for a single image GIF (non-animated)? I just want to convert a photo to a GIF color space and display it on the phone

Answer (score 1):

You can't without a third party GIF library. The question is why do you need it to be GIF? PNG provides all that you might need and it is well supported. If you are trying to do animation, look at UIImageView's [-animationImages property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationImages).

Comment: I want so save an animation as animated GIF, PNG does not support animation.

Comment: There are some rare cases(low color count images) where GIF will yield a better file size.