# iOS - Saving GIF from URL to Saved Photos album

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am receiving from a webservice an animated gif url.

how can i save that gif image to photo album ?

What i did is downloading the data and converting it to `UIImage` using category helper

```
UIImage* gifImage = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:self.resultImageUrl]];
```

and after that saving it useing

```
writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum
```

but the image is saved as first frame.

so i thought to try and save directly the `NSData` using

```
writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum
```

But i can't find any documentation about what to put in the metadata of the image so the album will know it's gif file.

Bottom line, I want the gif file will be visible in the user photo album and when he will send it using email client it will send it as gif animation and not just first frame

Please advise,
Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure iOS doesn't support gif images? I could be wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[self getCurrentGIFURL]];

[library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:data metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {}
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15677919/2439156)