# IOS - gif file was saved as jpeg

Tags: ios, image, gif

I downloaded an gif image from the network using `AFNetworking 2.0` then save it to camera roll using `ALAssetsLibrary`

```
[assetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[responseObject CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[responseObject imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        [App showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Save message failed"];
    }
    else
    {
        [App showAlertWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Saved success"];
    }
}];
```

Then I tried to retrieve this image from camera using `UIImagePickerViewController`, but the image I retrieved was not a GIF image but a jpeg image with reference url:

```
UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=2E7C87E4-5853-4946-B86B-CC8AAF094307&ext=JPG";
```

I don't know whether the fault is `ALAssetsLibrary` or `UIImagePickerViewController` and how to surpass it

Answer (score 0):

The photo library does not support GIFs.

It has support for `PHAssetMediaTypeImage` (a JPG), `PHAssetMediaTypeVideo` (a MOV), or `PHAssetMediaTypeAudio` (probably an M4A, not sure here).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/PHAssetMediaSubtype

Comment: That the Photos framework has somewhat limited format-saving support doesn't mean that the Library has. However, a `PHAssetMediaTypeImage` isn't restricted to JPEG, which is how saved PNGs, TIFFs and, yes, GIFs can appear in your Photos app. In fact, the docs to which you refer only say "The asset is a photo or other static image", with no reference to JPEG at all.

Answer (score -1):

The `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:` methods only save still images as JPEGs, as do the new Photos methods. However, there *are* ways of saving other formats, including (yes!) GIF.

You don't need to mess about with CGImageRefs—just grab the GIF data and then save it, using the `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:` method. Something like this:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somewhere/something.gif"]]];  
[library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:data 
    metadata:nil 
    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
      if (error) {
        [App showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Save message failed"];
      } else {
        [App showAlertWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Saved success"];
      }
    }];
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15677919/2439156).

If you want to *generate* a GIF, it's somewhat more complex, but simply saving one is straightforward.